# Recursive functions with integrals/derivatives return wrong results

Tags: functions, function-construction, recursion

I have the following recursive functions:

```
B[M] = 0;
P =  JacobiDN[u, m] Exp[I W x];
A[j_] := 
  A[j] = -I Integrate[(P Conjugate[B[j]] - Conjugate[P] B[j]), u] + 2^(j - 1) f[j]
B[j_] := B[j] = P A[j + 1] + I/2 D[B[j + 1], u]
```

with the following assumptions:

```
$Assumptions = 
  x ∈ Reals && W ∈ Reals && m >= 0 && m < 1 && u ∈ Reals && 
  M ∈ Integers && f[_] ∈ Reals
```

Noting that in this range of $m$ the elliptic cn, dn and sn functions are real for real $u$. You essentially start the recursion from the top at $j = M$ with $B$ then $A$, and then go down until $j = 0$.

My code works well for $j = M, M-1, M-2, M-3$, but at $M-4$ something weird happens. We first find $B$:

```
q = M - 4;
FullSimplify[TrigToExp[ComplexExpand[B[q]]]]
```

> ```
> 2^(-4 + M) E^(I x W) ((f[-3 + M] - m f[-1 + M]) JacobiDN[u, m] + 
>     I m (-f[-2 + M] + m f[M]) JacobiCN[u, m] JacobiSN[u, m])
> ```

which is correct if you compute this by hand.

As for $A$:

```
FullSimplify[TrigToExp[ComplexExpand[A[q]]]]
```

> ```
> 2^(-5 + M) (f[-4 + M] + m (-m f[M] - 2 (f[-2 + M] - m f[M]) JacobiCN[u, m]^2))
> ```

But if I calculate this manually:

```
B2 = 
  2^(-4 + M) E^(I x W) ((f[-3 + M] - m f[-1 + M]) JacobiDN[u, m] + 
     I m (-f[-2 + M] + m f[M]) JacobiCN[u, m] JacobiSN[u, m]);
Integrand = FullSimplify[P Conjugate[B] - Conjugate[P] B];
A2 = FullSimplify[- I Integrate[Integrand, u] + 2^(M - 4 - 1) f[M - 4]]
```

> ```
> 2^(-5 + M) (f[-4 + M] + 2 m (-f[-2 + M] + m f[M]) JacobiCN[u, m]^2)
> ```

As confirmed by hand, which is not the result the recursive functions give.

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. I haven't found any examples for defining recursion where you have both the parameter as well as variables you need to integrate over/differentiate.